# How to display the read csv file to proper dataframe using pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark

Im trying to read CSV file from the local file, and display the data to which the SQL needs to be applied. Here, Im able to read the file from the folder but on displaying the df, it is still in not readable format (screenshot is attached). I tried the below code to read and display the df. Can you please help me to over come this issue. Thannks.

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('PySpark Session').getOrCreate()
df = sc.read.option("header",True).csv("C:/Users/l/Desktop/data.csv") 
df.show()

another method :
df = sc.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('C:/Users/l/Desktop/data.csv')
```

Comment: I thin file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're having an encoding problem;

try chaining another `.option` with `encoding = 'UTF-8'`:

```py
df = sc.read.option("header",True).option("encoding", "UTF-8").csv("C:/Users/l/Desktop/data.csv")
```

Comment: Tried it but still the output is same.

Comment: try adding another option, `multiline = True`